# Trend Chart SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder

[image: SAMPLE CHART AND DATA]

I Have 3 columns OUTPUT,INPUT And WIP. Is there any way or chart expressions that will help me to achieve this kind of image above? I am using Report Builder.

TIA if anyone can help me.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: @pedram so far I used stacked column.. But I want to achieve like the image above

Comment: so you want something like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPmmZ.png ??

Comment: exactly sir! @pedram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert Chart, Used stacked column and then design your chart accordingly.

[image]

Add 3 Series and for the first series change it's property

[image]

Now, for scalar values (third row in each series) please check below image,

[image]

*Try this and let me know if you need more help.*

See below image to add fields/series

[image]

Comment: Hi sir @pedram i encounter problems  it seems like i did not understand 'Add 3 series' so what series i will add? When i run my report it only shows 2 column chart.

Comment: Check my updated answer and yes dont forget to set **First field series property - Axes and Chart Area Tab - Vertical Axis - Secondary** after adding first field.

Comment: thanks for this, I get the design that I want like your image above, but when I run it it only shows 2 columns, but thanks anyways maybe I forget something. Anyway thanks sir!

Comment: Thank you again sir. I tried it again and it works !

Comment: Welcome dear! Anytime! :)